# How do I reduce space between images in scroll view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a horizontal scroll view by using a horizontal LineaerLayoutManger. The problem that I am having is that their is too much space between my books images, I would like to have three book images next to each other in a horizontal scroll view. I tried setting the imageview scale  type to fit center, as well as adjusting view bounds to true. I would like my book images to be as shown in the attached picture. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0j7J.png)

**Book Row**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bookImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookTitleTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bookImage"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:text="A boy with tigers heart"
                android:textColor="#424242"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bookTitleTv"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"

                android:text="by Georeg Lopeaa"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bookAuthorTv"

                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"


                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:text="@string/vertical_ellipsis"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

width of main linear layout change into wrap_content